# Avoiding tenses problems

Tags: tenses

I think I'm facing many problems concerning the use of tense when I write things..so is there any app or website that can check my mistakes and correct them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct them, no. But a tool like [AutoCrit](https://www.autocrit.com/editing/support/tense-consistency/) can highlight all verbs written in a specific tense. I've never actually used this tool before so I can't speak to its quality, but you might find it helpful.

Keep in mind no fancy proofreading program actually understands your writing.  While a program might detect a verb's tense, it can't detect whether your slip into past perfect is an accident or an intentional flashback to a past event.

If you need to brush up on verb tenses, I can recommend [this web site](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbtenseintro.html).